# Query for comparing dynamic columns from similar tables

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-programming

I have two "LINKED SERVER" databases OLDDUMP and LATESTDUMP that have multiple tables. Each given table has the same name with same columns e.g both OLDDUMP and LATESTDUMP have table SIB, and both tables have same columns like (angle, tilt,param1,param2,param3.....param200 etc..). I need to compare each column in these tables (e.g. compare t1.tilt with t2.tilt..etc) and find unmatched records. The code i have works for few columns. But for 200+ columns i do not want to write the condition (where t1.angle<> t2.angle...etc)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  *
FROM LATESTDUMP...SIB$) t1

FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT *

FROM OLDDUMP...SIB$) t2

ON t1.id = t2.id

WHERE
t1.id IS NULL OR
t2.id IS NULL OR
t1.angle<>t2.angle OR
t1.tilt<>t2.tilt... 
t1.param1<>t2.param1
t1.param2<>t2.param2
.

t1.param200<>t2.param200
.
```

etc

The other reason i dont want to write a static query is the columns in table SIB can change in future

Comment: That sounds like a really badly structured table but you can get a list of columns from e.g. `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'whatever'`. Shouldn't be too hard to build a dynamic statement like `declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from.... on t1.id = t2.id where t1.id is null or t2.ir is null'; select @sql += ' or t1.' + quotename(column_name) + ' <> t2.' + quotename(column_name) from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'whatever';`

Comment: The database/ tables are basically linked excel files (with multiple sheets/columns) that are imported as SQL databases. Is it a better idea to first convert these files into proper SQL databases and then create dynamic query?... I'm relatively new to sql.. If you want u can share the exact table structure

Comment: information_schema.columns is not working with LINKED SERVER DB's